# Use contents of variable as name of dataframe for a function in r

Tags: r, dataframe, function

In R, I have a dataframe df1 that looks like

| variable | location |
| --- | --- |
| a | T1 |
| b | T2 |
| c | T1 |

location corresponds to the name of another dataframe. I am trying to create a function to update the contents of this dataframe  (in this case either T1 or T2).

My approach so far is as follows  `t <- df1$location[df1$variable == "a"]` this sets `t = "T1"` now I would like to create a function `doesSomething <- function(df)` and pass the value stored in t as an argument to the function. Ideally calling `doesSomething(t)` would allow me modify the dataframe T1 within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Using `match`.

```
transform(dat, value=cont$value[match(location, cont$loc)])
#   location name value
# 1       T1    a     1
# 2       T1    c     1
# 3       T2    b     2
```

Or `merge`.

```
merge(dat, cont, by.x='location', by.y='loc')
#   location name value
# 1       T1    a     1
# 2       T1    c     1
# 3       T2    b     2
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c"), location = c("T1", "T2", 
"T1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

cont <- structure(list(loc = c("T1", "T2"), value = 1:2), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: I am not trying to update dat. I am trying to update information in a separate dataframe. location refers to the name of the dataframe (in this case either T1 or T2) that needs to be modified in a larger function.

Comment: @keenan You also need to show the "other dataframe" in your question, as well as your expected output.